# Google Maps JS API v3 ComputeDistanceBetween returning NaN instead of distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know there are similar questions here, but seems like the setting isn't same.

The problem is as it stated in title - `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween` method **returning NaN instead of distance.**

related code is simple:

```
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(mapCons.mapStore[i].latitude, mapCons.mapStore[i].longitude);
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(centerLatLng, location);
        if(distance < distanceLimit){
          parsedMarkers.push(markers[i]);
        }
        console.log(distance)
```

I triple checked, `centerLatLng` and `location` both are valid `google.maps.LatLng` objects.
The imported `google maps js API V3` library does contains required library `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=*****************&libraries=geometry,places"`

What can possibly be a reason?

Comment: `I triple checked` - so, adding `console.log(location, centerLatLng)` between the first two lines of your code shows two google latlng objects?

Comment: after assigning  `location` variable - yes, right.
Also for both `.lat()`,`.lng()` returns correct values

Comment: no errors in the console at all when you load the page or run that code? I checked, and it looks like you're doing the right thing

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, for me the posted code works (if I make the correct inputs).  If I use a `google.maps.LatLngLiteral` for `centerLatLng` (which would be an issue), I get a javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: a.lat is not a function` and the `console.log` doesn't run.

Comment: Where I checked I did **not** include a version ... i.e. no `v=3.exp` nor did I specify libraries (just got them all)

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sw9oL2su/1/)

Comment: just checked all again. 
i didn't check `longtitude` actually ... 
there is a typo in my code, sry. (`mapCons.mapStore[i].longitude`)

Answer (score 0):

Checked all objects returning methods `.lat()`, but not `.lng()`
there is a typo in my code `longitude`